# R function arguments and environments/namespaces

Tags: r, namespaces

I'm having trouble understanding how R handles environments.  In
particular, I'd like to understand how to pass a dataframe to a
function, and use that dataframe's named columns as arguments.

Here's an example dataframe:

```
DF <- data.frame(pets   = c("puppies", "kitties"),
                 treats = c("kibble", "catnip"))
```

I can do:

```
paste(DF$pets, "like", DF$treats)
```

to get a vector that informs me that puppies like kibble, and
kitties like catnip.  So far, so good.

I can wrap this up in a function:

```
f <- function(x, y) {
    paste(x, "like", y)
}
```

which allows me to get the same output with either:

```
f(x = DF$pets, y = DF$treats)
with(DF, f(x = pets, y = treats))
```

That's great and all, but what I'd like to understand is how to
write a function `g` such that I can call it with:

```
g(x = pets, y = treats, data = DF)
```

What does `g` need to look like?

```
g <- function(x, y, data = what_do_i_do_here) {
    ## how do I set up the environment so that function g refers
    ## to x and y in the dataframe passed to the data argument?
    paste(x, "like", y)
}
```

Assume that `x` and `y` may refer to columns in the dataframe
passed as the `data` argument, *or* to variables bound in the
global environment.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommend you keep it simple and use quotes to reference columns. Then your problem is quickly solved:

```
g <- function(x, y, df) {
  paste(df[,x], "like", df[,y])
}

# This works
g("pets","treats",DF)
[1] "puppies like kibble" "kitties like catnip"
```

Passing them without quotes is possible too, but then the solution becomes an interactive function, and your data will need to be a `data.table`:

```
g2 <- function(x,y,df){
   x <- eval(substitute(x),df, parent.frame())
   y <- eval(substitute(y),df, parent.frame())
   paste(df[,x], "like", df[,y])
}

# This works given DF is a data.table
library(data.table)
DF <- data.table(DF)

g2(pets,treats,DF)
[1] "puppies like kibble" "kitties like catnip"
```

Comment: It's possible to do without resorting to data.table.

Comment: You can use deparse and substitute like f <- function(x){print(deparse(substitute(x)))} to get the input as characters. So f(hey) would print "hey".  From there you could use something like your first method. Sorry for formatting - my backtick key is apparently broken.