# passing an argument without quotes to an R function using its name in a switch statement

Tags: r

I have a function that refreshes the variable passed with a new value from the DB (under certain conditions). If the set of conditions are not met the return value is the variable itself with no change. The condition is not important but the way of passing the variable with quotes on its name is the trouble. Is there a way to pass the argument without quotes.

Consider a toy function `ref` below. We need to pass the variable straight as an argument. At the moment this function works only if I pass the name of the variable as a character vector.

```
abc=55
wxy=44
ref<-function(variable_name=NULL){
    if(exists(variable_name))
    {
        updated_df = switch(variable_name,
                        "abc"=paste("Variable1:",variable_name,get(variable_name)),
                        "wxy"=paste("Variable2:",variable_name,get(variable_name)),
                            "NOT FOUND")
    } else stop("passed variable  does not exist")
    if(updated_df=="NOT FOUND") updated_df = get(variable_name)
     updated_df
}
```

A similar but not same question was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34876406/r-function-arguments-and-environments-namespaces). It does not help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We could use the `enquo/quoname` from `rlang`

```
ref <- function(variable_name=NULL){
      variable_name <- rlang::quo_name(rlang::enquo(variable_name))
    if(exists(variable_name)){
        updated_df = switch(variable_name,
                        "abc"=paste("Variable1:",variable_name,get(variable_name)),
                        "wxy"=paste("Variable2:",variable_name,get(variable_name)),
                            "NOT FOUND")
    } else stop("passed variable  does not exist")
    if(updated_df=="NOT FOUND") updated_df = get(variable_name)
     updated_df
}

ref(abc)
#[1] "Variable1: abc 55"
```

In addition to the above change, we can also use `eval_tidy` on a quosure to replace the `get` and `glue` with `paste`

```
ref <- function(variable_name=NULL){
      vname <- enquo(variable_name)

      variable_name <- rlang::quo_name(vname)
    if(exists(variable_name)){
        updated_df = switch(variable_name,
                 "abc"= glue::glue("Variable1: {variable_name} {rlang::eval_tidy(vname)}"),
                 "wxy"= glue::glue("Variable2: {variable_name} {rlang::eval_tidy(vname)}"),
                 "NOT FOUND")
    } else stop("passed variable  does not exist")
    if(updated_df=="NOT FOUND") updated_df = vname
     updated_df
}

ref(abc)
#[1] "Variable1: abc 55"
```

Comment: I am not an expert on this, I just add what I found by trying out quo/enquo. rlang has the function `rlang::quo_get_expr' which evaluates the value from a quosure.

Comment: @MarcoStamazza It is possible that new versions added some functionalities

Answer (score 12):

**1)** Use `deparse(substitute(x))` to get the name.  No packages are used.

```
ref <- function(variable) {
    name <- deparse(substitute(variable))
    cat("name:", name, "value:", variable, "\n")
}

# test

abc <- 55
ref(abc)
## name: abc value: 55
```

**2)** Another possibility is to pass a formula:

```
ref2 <- function(formula) {
    name <- all.vars(formula)[1]
    variable <- get(name, environment(formula))
    cat("name:", name, "value:", variable, "\n")
}

# test

abc <- 55
ref2(~ abc)
## name: abc value: 55
```

Comment: The first solution with `rlang::quo_name(rlang::enquo(variable_name))` worked so I did not bother to check others. Is there any reason why we should go with the other solutions and not this one using `enquo`/`quoname`?

Comment: This answer has the advantages of no dependencies.  It does plainly state in the first line *No packages are used*.  If you are going to ask others to spend time to answer your questions you need to commit to review the answers.